# Warnings indicating old versions on My Bots will not disappear

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, botframework

I am building a Bot of Node.js on GoogleAppEngine.

A while ago, a warning is displayed in My bots of Microsoft BotFramework Webpage. That warning the version of Bot Builder is old.

I will detail the warning.

> "We've revised our security protocol. Update to Bot Builder 3.5+ or compatible security configuration by July 31, 2017 to keep your bot working."

I modified package.json and upgraded the version of "bot builder" to 3.7.0, but the warning will not disappear.

Does anyone know how to disappear this warning?

Comment: The warning is provided as a helpful reminder and will not affect the performance or functioning of your bot. As of this writing, current version of Node SDK for BotBuilder is v3.8.4.

Comment: I see.I thought that this behavior is affected if this warning clearly appears.
Thanks!